# How to insert a pair of std::pair inside another std::pair?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm declaring a map of string to a pair of pairs as follow:

```
std::map<std::wstring, 
         std::pair<std::pair<long, long>, 
                   std::pair<long, long>>> reference;
```

And I initialize it as:

```
reference.insert(L"First", 
                 std::pair<std::pair<long, long>, 
                           std::pair<long, long>>(std::pair<long, long>(-1, -1),
                           std::pair<long, long>(0, 0)));
```

However, Visual C++ gives me the error "C2664, No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous".

I'm new to using templates and STL and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please use typedef's and `std::make_pair` to make it legible.

Comment: I reformatted it to make it a *bit* easier on the eyes.

Comment: Instead of nesting all these `std::pair` s couldn't you switch over to using `std::tr1::tuple`? Boost has a tuple implementation too.

Comment: Yo yo Dawg.  I heard you like std::pair's, so I put a std::pair in your....

Comment: As I understand tuple is not implemented by all vendors. I'm trying to learn STL first before I move over to Boost.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `>>>` can not be parsed correctly (unless you have a C++0x compiler).

Change to `> > >`

This:

```
reference.insert("First",
```

Should be:

```
reference.insert(L"First",
                ^^^
```

Also there is a utility function to make the construction of pairs easier:

```
std::pair<std::pair<long, long>, std::pair<long, long>>(std::pair<long, long>(-1, -1), std::pair<long, long>(0, 0))
```

Can be:

```
std::make_pair(std::make_pair(-1L,-1L),std::make_pair(0L,0L))
```

Try this:

```
reference[L"First"]
    = std::make_pair(std::make_pair(-1L,-1L),std::make_pair(0L,0L));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited my question to add the L"" to my wstring to make the question more easier to "parse".

Comment: A better answer than mine, but note that inserting with `reference[key] = value` can give different behaviour to `reference.insert(make_pair(key,value))`; using `[]` will overwrite an existing element, while `insert` won't.

Answer (score 2):

C++ gets confused by the consecutive ">" when you close the template as it interprets that as the shift operator.

Add spaces between the closing templates, change >>> to > > >

Answer (score 2):

`map::insert` itself takes a single `std::pair` argument, rather than two arguments. You can tidy up the code by using `std::make_pair` (which infers the template arguments from the function arguments), to get something like:

```
reference.insert(std::make_pair("First", 
                                std::make_pair(std::make_pair(-1L,-1L),
                                               std::make_pair(0L,0L))));
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to use typedefs when debugging this sort of thing.

```
// test1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <map>
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    typedef std::pair<long, long> ElementType;
    typedef std::pair<ElementType, ElementType> ValueType;
    typedef std::wstring KeyType;
    std::map<KeyType, ValueType> reference;

    KeyType key = L"First";
    reference[key] = ValueType(ElementType(-1, -1), ElementType(0, 0));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is not such `insert()` function as the OP tries to use, even if you `#include <string>`. The sample code you posted works and is quite readable, but because you replaced the `insert()`, not because of the include as you seem to say...

Comment: If you remove the "you just need `<string>`" part, which I think is somewhat misleading, I would think it *is* helpful and would upvote it.

Comment: ok, you got it. I don't know if you realise you wrote "operator[] for insertion results in easier to read code" in your answer. As you say, insert doesn't exist!

Comment: Yeah I realize that and I saw your answer after posting mine and thought "who has downvoted this, operator[] is the way to go!". Then I got confused by the `<string>` stuff and went off to try if maybe actually some missing constructor for `wstring(const char*)` or such would produce an error message like in the question. I couldn't reproduce anything like that, though, so I decided to comment. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code by creating a helper function to create pairs of pairs, analog to the `std::make_pair` helper function that is available in the standard library. Also using the maps `operator[]` for insertion results in easier to read code:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W>
std::pair< std::pair<T,U>, std::pair<V,W> > make_pair_pair(T t, U u, V v, W w) {
   // using std::make_pair instead of the constructor for better readability
   return std::make_pair(std::make_pair(t, u), std::make_pair(v, w));
}

reference[L"First"] = make_pair_pair(1,2,3,4);
```