# How do I construct a MultiMap with two values (>> syntax error)?

Tags: c++, stl

I currently have this code snippet:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> myPair;

std::multimap<int,pair > topNodes;

topNodes.insert(std::make_pair(someNode->counter,
std::make_pair(someNode->phrase,title)));
```

How do I create this multimap that has a key and two associated values?
Or is there any better ways to do this?

> error: no viable conversion from
>         '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator<__value_type<[...], struct
>         std::__1::pair, class
>         std::__1::basic_string >>, class std::__1::__tree_node, class std::__1::basic_string > >, void
>         *> *, [...]>>' to '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator<__value_type<[...],
>         class std::__1::basic_string>, class std::__1::__tree_node >, void *>
>         *, [...]>>'

I used [How to insert a pair of std::pair inside another std::pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813923/how-to-insert-a-pair-of-stdpair-inside-another-stdpair) as a reference for the insert.

Comment: First of all you want to use a `typedef` instead of `#define`!

Comment: Because there is no [`std::multimap::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) that matches those arguments.

Comment: If you're going to ask a question about a compilation error, include the text of the error in your question. You'll get better responses.

Comment: Oh, @juanchopanza, your right. The error being thrown is indeed at  the insert.

Comment: You don't need to tell me that, I know I'm right ;-)

Comment: Haha, how do I go about fixing the insert though? Should I use std::tuple?

Comment: Read the reference in my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::multimap<int,pair > topNodes; //Error cause > > not compiling
```

Why do you think it should? What's `pair` at this point?

<sub>Remember [`std::pair<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) needs to have correct template parameters to instatiate it.</sub>

> Or is there any better ways to do this?

You probably meant something like this:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> myPair;

std::multimap<int,myPair> topNodes;
// ...
```